# How can we draw a line between two buttons?

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can I draw a line using canvas to connect two buttons in android ?

If I create the button in the activity class and draw the line in the view, and do `setContentView(my view class obj)`, the buttons are not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same problem. you can add these lines

```
getWindow().addContentView(view,
new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Don't set your setContentView to view object. set it to layout. then add these lines.
Hope it works.